# How to generate the command-line equivalents of a GUI-based VirtualBox VM creation?

Tags: virtualbox

Suppose I go through the GUI-guided steps to create a VirtualBox VM.

I want to determine the command-line equivalents of all the steps I just went through, so that I can put them in a script.

Is there a way to generate this information from the (just-created) VM?

Comment: You should maybe consider Vagrant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the OVF export function (for a VM called `my_vm`):

```
VBoxManage export my_vm --output my_vm.ovf
VBoxManage import -n my_vm.ovf
```

The last command offers a preview + options to customize, like this:

```
VBoxManage import my_vm.ovf --vsys 0 --vmname my_vm_copy
```

Sources:

- http://nakkaya.com/2012/08/30/create-manage-virtualBox-vms-from-the-command-line/
- http://www.trimentation.com/wp/?p=100